# How to make header files included by <ClInclude Include=.../> visible globally in the project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vcxproj

When I have this line in my .vcxproj file

```
<ClInclude Include="..\include\something_*.h"/>
```

And then in my .c file located somewhere else I use a simple

```
#include "something_a.h"
```

The header file won't be visible in compilation, although it is visible in the project/solution explorer in the Visual Studio.

I know that I can simply add my include folder to the additional include directories list, and the compiler will use that directory to search for include files, but isn't it something that  tag already supposed to do by itself?

Comment: It just doesn't.  The build system only pays attention to `<ClCompile>`.  Since you never compile a .h file.  `<ClInclude>` is only interesting to the IDE.

Comment: So what is the common practice in that case? Do I use only the "additional include directories" option? Otherwise it seems like a double definition of the same header files in one .vcxproj file.